# c++ friend function implemented in a class can't access privates

Tags: c++, friend, friend-function

I'm trying to define 2 classes, declare a friend function in one of them and implement it in the other.
I am actually trying to get exactly what found in this post working:

[How can friend function be declared for only one particular function and class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966255/how-can-friend-function-be-declared-for-only-one-particular-function-and-class)

I read the answer and thought it made sense.
then implemented it in my code and it gave me the errors:

**Edited:**

Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup ...\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) - *(solved by adding main function)*

Error 2 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals ...\Debug\Project.exe 1 1..  - *(solved by adding main function)*

Error 3 IntelliSense: member "one::data1" (declared at line 19) is inaccessible ...\Friends.cpp - **(Exists even after cleaning and rebuilding project)**

I thought it might be a problem with how I implemented it, so I did a copy-paste to the  code in the answer:

```
class one;

class two
{
 private:
    int data2;
 public:
    two()
    {
       data2 = 200;
    }
    // this goes fine, because the function is not yet defined. 
    int accessboth(one a);
};

class one
{
private:
    int data1;
public:
    one()
    {
       data1 = 100;
    }
    friend int two::accessboth(one a);
};

// don't forget "inline" if the definition is in a header. 
inline int two::accessboth(one a)
{
    return (a.data1 + (*this).data2);
}
```

but I got the same error in the same place: **a.data1** was *inaccessible*

I then searched and found more examples that suggest the same technique to solve the problem, but they all gave me the same *inaccessible* error in the same place...

Is there something I'm missing? should the provided example (suggested solution from previous post) work?
Something changed in the specification maybe?

thank you for any help.
D

P.S
I tried commenting on the previous post in order not to open a new question about this, but was unable to comment due to low reputation (I'm new here).

Comment: [Compiles for me](http://ideone.com/ttJTZG). What compiler are you using?

Comment: Do post *unedited* error messages.

Comment: @sftrabbit I'm using the Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 (visual studio 2013 express for windows desktop).

Comment: Intellisense errors are irrelevant if you get other errors. Fix those first.

Comment: @n.m. adding a main function like **tumdum** suggested left me with only the intellisense error, which still indicates the _inaccessible_ error, the same as before.

Comment: If you get only intellisense errors but your build succeeds, try cleaning and rebuilding from scratch.

Comment: @theexplorer Intellisense is not the compiler. Does your program compile? If it does, there is no problem.

Comment: As sftrabbit said, Intellisense uses a different "compiler" to evaluate the code. In C++ this can cause different behaviour between the real compiler and Intellisense. As long as it compiles without errors, it should be ok. We get this all the time. Fortunately, Intellisense errors only show up in the file you're viewing, not for the whole solution. You can file a bug at Microsoft Connect if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing main function. Like this one for example:

```
int main() {
  one a;
  two b;
  b.accessboth(a);
}
```

Put it on the bottom of your file and it should compile.

Comment: thank you, it did take the 2 other errors I had, I still have the _inaccessible_ intellisense error...